# Moving site to new domain and path (SEO)

Tags: seo

So lets say there are two websites

website.com
blogwebsite.com

I want to move blogwebsite.com to website.com/blog

This has already been done, 301's are set up and working properly. blogwebsite.com weeks later is still showing up in google search results despite the 301's and submitting sitemaps of the old site to google. In trying to be more direct with google I tried to use the change of address tool, but I get the error

> The old site redirects to website.com/blog, which does not correspond to the new site you chose.

I created a property for website.com/blog but the change of address tool does not allow me to select that property, only the top level one.

Is there something else I should be doing or do I simply need to let google take its time figuring out that all the indexed links from blogwebsite.com are redirecting

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for Google to re-crawl all your existing URLs and update their index. If your site contains many pages it can take months to finish all the updates. As long as you have correctly setup 301 there's nothing to worry.